# for loop on files that don't exist

Tags: bash, file, loops, for-loop, exists

I want to process a set of files (*.ui) in the current directory. The following script works as expected if some *.ui files are found. But if no .ui file exist the current directory, the for loop is entered all the same. Why is that ?

```
for f in *.ui
do
    echo "Processing $f..."
done
```

It prints :

```
Processing *.ui...
```

Comment: FAQ: `shopt -s nullglob`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

From `man bash`:

> **nullglob**
>           If  set,  bash  allows  patterns  which  match no files (see Pathname Expansion
>           above) to expand to a null string, rather than themselves.

Comment: I like this solution because it is close to C/C++. More details here : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob

Comment: Good one! What's the default for this flag? Or what's the way to unset it?

Comment: use `shopt -u` to disable and `shopt -s` to enable.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the how, the 'why' is that bash will first try to match `*.ui` to files, but if that doesn't work (it gets no results) it will assume you meant the string `"*.ui"`.

```
for f in "*.ui"
do
    echo "Processing $f..."
done
```

wil indeed print `"Processing *.ui"`.